# Objective-C JSON - go deeper into JSON?

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

I have the following extract of response of the JSON:

```
"em_phone": "987654321",
    "stage": 2,
    "stage_count": 2,
    "allowed_staff": 1,
    "expected_staff": null,
    "active_staff": 0,
    "url": "/api2/jobs/508190271",
    "user": {
        "owned": false,
        "contractor": false,
        "pending": false,
        "will_block": false,
        "blocking": false,
        "writable": true,
        "flow": {
            "blind": false
        }
```

How i can access to "contractor" from "user" ?

The code of read the JSON:

```
for (NSDictionary *dataDict in jsonObjects) {
    NSString *title_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"id"];
    NSString *author_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"user"];
    NSString *thumbnail_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"created_at"];
```

The problem is the following line:

```
NSString *author_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"user"];
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

:"user" is a dictionary. Change your line to

```
NSDictionary *author_data = [dataDict objectForKey:@"user"];
```

and access the data `[author_data objectForKey:@"contractor"]`

Comment: And how i can define the variable that save the information in a String?

Comment: You mean the value of contractor? Why would you want to do that? Contractor is a boolean and therefore represented as NSNumber.

Comment: Sorry but what happened if "contractor" is a String like this  "contractor": "name",

Comment: Then you could directly reference it as NSString. `NSString * contractorName = [author_data objectForKey:@"contractor"]` make sure to verify whether the value is a string, in case you are not sure.

Answer (score 0):

`[dataDict objectForKey:@"user"]` will return another NSDictionary.

You should write something like:

```
NSDictionary *user = [dataDict objectForKey:@"user"];
```

Then:

```
BOOL isContractor = [[user objectForKey:@"contractor"] boolValue];
```

Comment: Thanks but what happened if "contract" is a String?

Comment: According to the paste JSON extract, the contractor node will be a NSNumber. Do you think the structure of your JSON could change?

Comment: i have the problem to show the data into a tableview, but i need the value of "contractor" to show.

Comment: I don't get it. But basically, if you want to display the word "true" or "false" from a boolean value, you could do ```NSString *contractor = [[user objectForKey:@"contractor"] boolValue] ? @"true" : @"false";```

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking into this for the past week. I decided to write my own solution. It is very simple and built upon existing Apple functionality.

See here: https://github.com/gslinker/GSObject

And here: http://digerati-illuminatus.blogspot.com/2016/01/objective-c-and-json-convert-subclass.html

For your data model object have it inherit from GSObject instead of NSObject. Here is an example of ThingOne with inherits from GSObject:

```
ThingOne* object1 = [[ThingOne alloc] init];
object1.name = @"John Jones";


NSData* jsonData1 = [object1 toJsonDataWithOptions:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted];
NSString *jsonString1 = [object1 toJsonStringWithOptions:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted];

NSDictionary<NSString *,id> *dict1 =  [GSObject dictionaryWithValues:object1];

NSString *roundTripJson1 = [object1 toJsonStringWithOptions:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted];




//
//  ThingOne.h
//  JasonStuff
//
//  Created by Geoffrey Slinker on 12/28/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Slinkworks LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GSObject.h"
#import "ThingTwo.h"

@interface ThingOne : GSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) ThingTwo *thingTwo;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *values;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDictionary *dict;
@property int myInt;
@property float myFloat;
@property BOOL myBool;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber* someMoney;


@end

//
//  ThingOne.m
//  JasonStuff
//
//  Created by Geoffrey Slinker on 12/28/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Slinkworks LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ThingOne.h"

@implementation ThingOne

@synthesize name;
@synthesize thingTwo;
@synthesize values;
@synthesize dict;
@synthesize myInt;
@synthesize myFloat;
@synthesize myBool;
@synthesize someMoney;

- (instancetype)init
{
self = [super init];

thingTwo = [[ThingTwo alloc] init];

thingTwo.stuff = @"Thing Two Stuff";
thingTwo.someOtherStuff = @"Thing Two Other Stuff";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormater = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormater setDateFormat:@"yyyy-mm-dd"];
thingTwo.someDate =  [dateFormater dateFromString:@"1963-10-07"];

values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Value1", @"Value2", @"Value3", nil];

dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"value1", @"key1", @"value2", @"key2", nil];

myInt = 5431;
myFloat = 123.456f;
myBool = YES;

someMoney = [NSNumber numberWithInt:503];

return self;
}

@end

//
//  ThingTwo.h
//  JasonStuff
//
//  Created by Geoffrey Slinker on 12/28/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Slinkworks LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "GSObject.h"

@interface ThingTwo : GSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *stuff;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *someOtherStuff;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *someDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *nullString;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *nullDate;

@end

//
//  ThingTwo.m
//  JasonStuff
//
//  Created by Geoffrey Slinker on 12/28/15.
//  Copyright © 2015 Slinkworks LLC. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ThingTwo.h"

@implementation ThingTwo

@synthesize stuff;
@synthesize someOtherStuff;
@synthesize someDate;

- (instancetype)init
{
self = [super init];

someDate = [NSDate date];

return self;
}

@end
```

Here is an example of the JSON output:

```
{
  "values" : [
    "Value1",
    "Value2",
    "Value3"
  ],
  "myInt" : 5431,
  "myFloat" : 123.456,
  "myBool" : true,
  "someMoney" : "$503.00",
  "thingTwo" : {
    "stuff" : "Thing Two Stuff",
    "nullDate" : null,
    "someDate" : "1963-01-07 07:10:00 +0000",
    "nullString" : null,
    "someOtherStuff" : "Thing Two Other Stuff"
  },
  "name" : "John Jones",
  "dict" : {
    "key1" : "value1",
    "key2" : "value2"
  }
}
```